# Javascript equivalent of gevent.sleep(0)

Tags: javascript, python, multitasking, gevent

In Python, there's a library called [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) that enables cooperative multitasking. Sometimes it's useful to have two long-running functions yield execution to one another. Example:

```
def long_running_func1():
    while True:
        # processor intensive
        gevent.sleep()
```

The [gevent.sleep](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html#gevent.sleep) call puts a task to sleep. Without arguments it simply yields execution to other tasks.

Using Javascript in the browser, I find myself wanting something similar so that in between processor intensive work, the UI has a chance to update. Something like:

```
var data = [];

setTimeout(function () {
    while (true) {
        // Update UI with data.slice(data.length - 5, 5)
        // gevent.sleep(0);
    }
}, 0);

setTimeout(function () {
    while (true) {
        // var value = computation;
        // data.append(value);
        // gevent.sleep(0);
    }
}, 0);
```

Does Javascript offer some kind of multi-tasking that would permit this pattern?

The pattern I've been using is to rewrite the above as:

```
var data = [];

function update_ui() {
    // Update UI with data.slice(data.length - 5, 5)
}

function repeatedly() {
    var value = computation;
    data.append();
    update_ui();
    setTimeout(repeatedly, 0);
}

repeatedly();
```

But as the code becomes more complex this pattern inevitably involves many more functions chained with setTimeout and it's not very readable.

Is there a better pattern than above?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is event driven by nature, but you always work on a single thread.

IO is the only thing that is always handled asynchonously (no blocking IO functions in browser javascript).

Split your long computation in chunks, and use the the async library to give structure to your code if you want to do long computations, and avoid locking the UI.

https://github.com/caolan/async

Something like:

```
var LongTask = function() {
    this.state = 0;
    this.result = 'whatever';
};

LongTask.prototype.start = function(callback) {
    async.whilst(
        this._isFinished.bind(this),
        this._doChunk.bind(this),
        function(error) {
            callback(error, this.result);
        }
    );
};

LongTask.prototype._isFinished = function() {
    return this.state > 1000;
};

LongTask.prototype._doChunk = function(callback) {
    var chunkEnd = this.state + 10;
    while (this.state++ < chunkEnd) {
         .... do something ...
    }

    // In NodeJS, you would call process.nextTick(callback)
    setTimeout(callback, 0);
};
```

And later, or in some other file

```
var task = new Task();
task.start(function(error, result) {
    // work is done without locking the whole process

});
```